# Implementar um botão de curtir em PHP e mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tentando implementar um botão de curtir em um sistema que estou criando de teste. Ele já altera o valor da curtida no banco de dados, porém eu tenho que colocar o valor num campo input que coloquei. Então a cada número que eu coloco no input e clico em curtir ele faz o update no meu banco de dados. Gostaria de saber como faço para não precisar de inserir o valor no input e a cada vez que eu clicar ele somar mais um número no valor que já tem no banco de dados. Eis o código:

Index.php

```
<?php 

  require_once "conecta.php";

  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from curtida");
  $curtida = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Curtir</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/claudina.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <section class="recipiente margem-topo-50">
   <form action="envia_curtir.php" method="post">
   <input type="number" name="curtida" />
   <button class="icones icone-polegares-para-cima"></button>
   <?=$curtida['curtidas'];?>
    </form>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

enviar_curtir.php

```
<?php

  require_once "conecta.php";
  require_once "funcoes.php";

  $curtida = $_POST['curtida'];

  curtir($conexao, $curtida);

  header("Location: index.php");

?>

funcoes.php

<?php

  function curtir($conexao, $curtida) {

    $query = "update curtida set curtidas= $curtida";

    return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente alterar o `update`:

```
function curtir($conexao, $curtida) {

    $query = "update curtida set curtidas = curtidas + 1";

    return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
  }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!